# one controller value to another controller not going in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

i am creating a controller name **ProductController** on there have a method

```
 public void DeliveryLocationCookies()
    {


            HttpCookie deliveryloccookies1 = Request.Cookies["deliveryloccookies"];
            if (deliveryloccookies1 != null)
            {
                ViewBag.deliveryloccookies = deliveryloccookies1["deliveryloccookies"];

            }



    }
```

Now i am creation another controller name **HomeController**
on there i am creating a object of **ProuctController**

```
ProductController pc = new ProductController();
```

an creating one action result

```
public ActionResult view()
    {
        pc.DeliveryLocationCookies();

        return view();
    }
```

but from there produce exception

** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at TestSite.Controllers.ProductController.DeliveryLocationCookies() in e:\WINUSB\TestSite\TestSite\Controllers\ProductController.cs:line 353**

i cant understand that how can access other controller method even i dont know it's right process or not.

Comment: Extract `DeliveryLocationCookies` into a separate method, which takes `Request` as a parameter. Calling methods between controllers gets very messy.

Comment: All HTTP data is passed to the controller class using the request context. When you instantiate a controller manually, context won't have some of the important data including HTTP related ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because your controller needs to initializes itself. During this process it sets the Request property (that you are using) and others properties.

Take a look at this answer, it is similar to yours (and the solution too): [Session is null when calling method from one controller to another...MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388357/session-is-null-when-calling-method-from-one-controller-to-another-mvc)

Regards,